# Flutter showing Material Icons fail

Tags: flutter

In created new project in `Flutter` i'm wondering why Flutter doesn't show icons from `Material` package, please see this below screen shot which that's simple piece of my application

[image]

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:xxxxx/src/partials/home_app_bar.dart';
import 'package:xxxxx/src/partials/home_card.dart';
import 'package:xxxxx/src/partials/top_slider.dart';

...

Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
  children: [
    OutlineButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      child: Text('Read More'),
    ),
    IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.fingerprint), onPressed: () {}),
    IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.comment), onPressed: () {}),
    IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.subdirectory_arrow_right), onPressed: () {}),
  ],
),
```

`flutter doctor -v` output:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.508], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.22.0 at F:\software\flutter
    • Framework revision d408d302e2 (10 days ago), 2020-09-29 11:49:17 -0700
    • Engine revision 5babba6c4d
    • Dart version 2.10.0


[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
    • Android SDK at F:\software\sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.2
    • ANDROID_HOME = F:\software\sdk
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 49.0.2
    • Dart plugin version 193.7547
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • WAS LX1A (mobile) • 2XJDU17C14006203 • android-arm64 • Android 8.0.0 (API 26)

• No issues found!
```

`pubspec.yaml`:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0
  sailor: ^0.7.1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/
    - assets/images/
    - assets/images/icons/
```

Comment: Have you tried to hot restart your application? If that doesn't work, stop the app and run it again.

Comment: I tried it in dartpad. It worked for me.

Comment: @abiudrn yes, i uninstalled application and tested too

Comment: @TirthPatel i'm wondering why i have this problem

Comment: It could be an issue with your imports... Could you include them in the question?

Comment: @abiudrn i updated post with imports

Answer (score 0):

you need to set `uses-material-design` to true in `pubspec.yaml file`

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

Comment: this option deprecated